# How to get forms authentication ticket to respecting cookie expiration date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having an issue where users of my website login sessions are expiring way before it should.

Here is my login method”

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var mcookie = new MyCompanyCookie();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var myRepo = new MyCompanyRepositry())
        {
            var passwordHash = MyCompany.Web.Portal.Helpers.Security.CreatePasswordHash(model.Password);

            var userAccount = myRepo.GetMyCompanyUser(model.UserName,model.PartnerAccessCode);

            if(userAccount != null && userAccount.Password == passwordHash && userAccount.PartnerAccessCode == model.PartnerAccessCode.ToUpper())
            {
                mcookie.GetMMformsauthentication(userAccount, model.RememberMe);


                   return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name,access code or password provided is incorrect.");
            }


        }
```

And forms authentication ticket:

public void GetMMformsauthentication(UserAccount useraccount, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        const string UnknownUsername = "anonymous";

```
    // Composing UserData to be stored in the auth cookie
    var userCookieData = new MarvMentUserCookieData()
    {
        UserId = useraccount.UserID,
        Password = useraccount.Password,
        PartnerAccessCode = useraccount.PartnerAccessCode
    };

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, string.IsNullOrEmpty(useraccount.UserID) ? UnknownUsername : useraccount.UserID, DateTime.Now,
                                                                     DateTime.Now.AddDays(100), createPersistentCookie, userCookieData.ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    var hashedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

    var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashedCookie); // Hashed ticket
    authCookie.HttpOnly = true;
    authCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    authCookie.Path = ticket.CookiePath;
    authCookie.Secure = false;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(authCookie);
}
```

}

And expiration settings inmy Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Here you can see that the forms expiration settings is set 2880 minutes however users are beign logged out after around 5-10 minutes.

The cookie is set to expire in 100 days

Does anyone have and idea what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks issue is not with session in authentication tag. Just check what happens if cookies stuff is commented... If Session retained for more time, then focus on cookie stuff.